# match specific value that isn't at same row and column

Tags: r, tidyverse

My data isn't generated chronologically, however, I wish to calculate the accuracy when the participant responses at the desired time range. my dataframe looks like this (simple example)

```
a<-data.frame("time1"=c(6.28,17,49,72), "target"=c(5.8,17.3,71.5,85),"catch"=c(8,48.5,68,80))
```

I wish to know whether `time1`(subject response time) occurs in the range of `target` time + additional duration of 0.9 if so the accuracy=1. However, the `time1` isnt at correct time order, as participants might also respond to the `catch`, in this case, accuracy=0. On the other hand, participants might respond correctly, but not in the same row of `target` (for example: `a$time1[4]`=72 is correct response because it located at the correct range: 72.4 (`a$target[3]`:71.5+0.9) but not in the same row.

Here is the expected outcome (4th colum):

```
outcome<-data.frame("time1"=c(6.28,17,49,72), "target"=c(5.8,17.3,71.5,85),"catch"=c(8,48.5,68,80),
           "expOutcome.ACC"=c(1,1,0,1))
```

Any advice to know whether each time1 value is answered correctly by looking through two columns of `target` and `catch`? Will be much appreciated if can use `tidyverse`/`purr` package to solve the problem.

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you show the expected output.  Perhaps `with(a, findInterval(target + catch, time1))`

Comment: @akrun thanks for this good idea of adding the expected outcome (see question). The problem here is that there is no regular time interval amongst `time1`, `target`, `catch`  (it is the randomized condition). But we can know when participant answers correctly the `time1` value is in the range of `target`+ 0.9 duration. So for instance, the first expected acc is `1`, because of `the 1st target` is 5.8s and participant answered at 6.28s ( in the range of 5.8s+0.9s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

a %>% 
  gather(key = event, value = time) %>% 
  arrange(time) %>% 
  mutate(acc = event == "time1" & 
           lag(event, default = "dummy") == "target" &
           time <= lag(time, default = -Inf) + 0.9)

#     event  time   acc
# 1  target  5.80 FALSE
# 2   time1  6.28  TRUE
# 3   catch  8.00 FALSE
# 4   time1 17.00 FALSE
# 5  target 17.30 FALSE
# 6   catch 48.50 FALSE
# 7   time1 49.00 FALSE
# 8   catch 68.00 FALSE
# 9  target 71.50 FALSE
# 10  time1 72.00  TRUE
# 11  catch 80.00 FALSE
# 12 target 85.00 FALSE
```